# Cambiar el nombre de los ficheros generados tras hacer npm run build

Tags: vue3

En mi proyecto con vue3 al hacer npm run build me genera los archivos en la carpeta dist.
Los archivos generados llevan un hash quedando el nombre del archivo tal que así: chunk-2d216214.8ece6c8e.js
Lo que necesito es añadir algo a ese nombre de archivo que se genera automáticamente para tener una especie de seguimiento o versión de los archivos, es decir lo que busco es que quede así:

wcV1abril-chunk-2d216214.8ece6c8e.js
y no así
chunk-2d216214.8ece6c8e.js

Soy nuevo con Vue y todo el ecosistema node y webpack.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 2):

Ya he conseguido resolver mi duda, pego la solución por si a alguien le viene bien,

```
const dateBuildWC = new Date()
const dateBuildFormat = dateBuildWC.toLocaleDateString().replaceAll('/','_')
const nameWcVersion = 'wc_version_'


module.exports = {  

    // filenameHashing: false, 
    configureWebpack: config => {
            if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
                config.output.filename = `js/${nameWcVersion}${dateBuildFormat}.[name].[contenthash:8].min.js`
                config.output.chunkFilename = `js/${nameWcVersion}${dateBuildFormat}.[name].[contenthash:8].min.js`
            } else {
                config.output.filename = 'js/[name].js'
                config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name].js';
            }
    },
    css: {
        extract: { 
            ignoreOrder: true,
            filename: `css/${nameWcVersion}${dateBuildFormat}.[name].[contenthash:8].css`,
            chunkFilename: `css/${nameWcVersion}${dateBuildFormat}.[name].[contenthash:8].css`, 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).